# Source for derivation of acquisition price for given IRR and cash flows

Tags: returns, discounting, return

Does anyone know a quotable source - book/academic or practitioner's paper - that derives the acquisiton price for a target firm when the buyer's desired IRR and all cash flows over time of the target firm (except those depending on the acquisition price) are known?

It is very easy to do yourself, but I am looking for a quotable source.

I am on purpose not posting the equations here, because I only would like to find a source; I am not asking you to do the derivation yourself. Thank you!